# C++ find_if causing crash with bind function

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, c++17, bind

The situation is a little complicated, but I'm going to try to explain it as best as I can.
I'm trying to get a pointer to an object from a vector of object pointers where one of the object's attributes matches a variable string.  To do this, I'm binding the string variable to a function and then using the bound function to try and find that object pointer.  However, it keeps crashing whenever I try this.  I've tried a bunch of different tests to find the problem, but I'm still clueless.  Here's the relevant code:

```
class A {
std::string n;
...
public:
const std::string getN() {
return n
}
};
static bool checkN(std::string n1, A* a) {
        if (a->getN() == n1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
void function() {
using namespace std::placeholders;
A* a;
std::string compare = "Yes";
const std::vector<A*> As; //As[0].n = "Yes";
auto check = std::bind(checkN, compare, _1);
a = (*std::find_if(As.begin(), As.end() - 1, check));  //This is the line where it crashes.
}
```

Note that this is something of a simplified version, but I think it gets the point across.  Any suggestions?
Edit:  Made some syntax errors in trying to simplify the code.  Fixed them.

Comment: I recommend compiling with address sanitizer as a first step. However, the relevant code isn't nearly as useful to us as a [mre], especially when it comes to crashes, where the problem can easily be in a place that looks irrelevant.

Comment: What are the values of your variables at the time of the crash? What makes you think `As.end() - 1` is valid? Or even useful -- are you trying to ignore the last element?

Comment: Your code doesn't show you putting anything into your vector...  Here is an example of it working: https://onlinegdb.com/KziZkSl7y  The main worry is that your code only works if the vector actually contains the matching item - if it doesn't you dereference the end iterator which is UB.  Here is an example that handles that case: https://onlinegdb.com/WAPHS5Dxl

Answer (score 4):

`As` is a `const std::vector<A*>` that contains *no* elements inside it, so dereferencing the iterator returned by `std::find_if(...)` in this case is *Undefined Behavior*.

Since you don't mention anything about why you do `As.end() - 1` in `std::find_if(...)`, I will assume that you did so in an attempt to get rid of the segmentation fault, but I am afraid that won't get rid of the above problem either.

Now, coming to what you *do* need to prevent this sort of *Undefined Behavior* from occurring is to check whether the iterator returned by `std::find_if(...)` is ***not past the last element of the container*** (i.e., check whether `std::find_if(...) != As.end()` and only then should you try to dereference the iterator returned by `std::find_if(...)`.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// ...

int main() {
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    std::string compare = "Yes";

    const std::vector<A*> As;

    // Store the iterator returned by 'std::find_if(...)' inside a variable
    auto it = std::find_if(As.begin(), As.end(), std::bind(checkN, compare, _1));

    // Check whether the iterator is NOT past the last element i.e. check if it is not equals 'As.end()'
    if (it != As.end())
        std::cout << std::quoted(compare) << " found at index " << std::distance(As.begin(), it) << "!" << std::endl;
    // Otherwise, if the iterator is, in fact, equals 'As.end()', then it is safe to assume that the element was not found
    else
        std::cout << std::quoted(compare) << " was not found." << std::endl;
}
```